# Cannot add child to XML node in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to add a child note to an XML file using PHP. I have used the same method about 5 times before and each one works as expected, however this method is using a different XML structure on a new file (which I think might be part of the problem).

The method causing me the problem is this:

```
function addCourseToProject($name, $project){
    $projects = self::getRoles();
    $theProject = $projects->xpath('project[name = "'.$project.'"]');
    echo $theProject->name;
    $theCourses = $theProject[0]->courses->addchild("course", $name);
    $projects->asXml("projects.xml");

}
```

The XML file looks like this:

```
<projects>
    <project>
        <name>Alpha</name>
            <courses>
                <course>Beta</course>
                <course>Charlie</course>
            </courses>
    </project>
</project>
```

And `getRoles()` looks like this:

```
function getRoles(){
     $roles = simplexml_load_file("projects.xml") or die("ERROR: Unable to read file");
return $roles;
}
```

I'm at a loss here, I have no idea why this is different from the other adding functions (see below).

---

Should you need it, here is an example of what my other methods look like:

```
function addModule($courseName, $name, $link){  
    $xml = self::getXml();#get the xml file
    $course = $xml->xpath('course[name = "'.$courseName.'"]');
    $module = $course[0]->addChild("module");
    $module->addChild("name", $name);
    $module->addChild("link", $link);
    $xml->asXml("data.xml");
    echo self::toJSON($course);
}
```

and the `getXML()` method:

```
function getXml(){
     $xml=simplexml_load_file("data.xml") or die("ERROR: Unable to read file");
    return $xml;
}
```

Comment: no, i'm looking for a project whose first child is `<name>"Alpha"</name>`... although, i could restructure the XML file if that would make this easier?

Comment: ah wait, no i can't, that would require me re-writing a number of functions :/

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, given that sample XML is valid (currently `<projects>` doesn't have corresponding closing tag), new course got added correctly : http://missingbrackets.com/codepad/editor/YM4Kp3. Could you post minimal codes demonstrating the problem?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by minimal codes?

Comment: hmm, you seem to have solved my problem without realizing it... i was using `$projects->xpath('project[name = "'.$project.'"]');` and you were using `$projects->xpath('//project[name = "'.$project.'"]');`

Comment: yeh, i just tested it on real values, you have deffinately found the solution, thanks :D

Comment: @JamieMcAllister fyi, regarding minimal codes, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258845/can-we-create-a-help-center-topic-that-outlines-what-a-sscce-mwe-means-for-sta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that the problem was caused by the fact that `<project>` element is nested within the XML document. You can use `descendant-or-self` axis (`//` for the abbreviated syntax) to get nested element like so :

```
$theProject = $projects->xpath('//project[name = "'.$project.'"]');
```

or specify the complete path :

```
$theProject = $projects->xpath('/projects/project[name = "'.$project.'"]');
```